# getenv(QUERY_STRING) in C CGI

Tags: html, c, cgi

C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  FILE *ptr;
  char m[200];
  char *data = malloc(200);
  data=getenv("QUERY_STRING");
  sscanf(data,"%s", m);
  printf("%s", m);
  ptr=fopen("c:/test.txt", "w");
  fprintf(ptr, "%s", m);
  fclose(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

//gcc -g print.c -o print.exe

HTML file:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>CGI Server</h2>
    <p>
      <form action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/print.exe">
    <div><label>value: <input name="m" size="10"></label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Run"></div>
      </form>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

If the input into the webpage form is c:/data.txt then the result is: c%3A%2Fdata.txt

What happened? Why are the / and the : damaged in the output? it seems the problem is with QUERY_STRING because getenv("PATH") doesn't present this problem.

Comment: I'm not a C expect, but I'm sure there are preexisting libraries for CGI and form data parsing. It's an area that is more complicated than it looks, so please don't reinvent the wheel!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "problem" is due to [URL-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). You'll need to URL-decode the value you get from QUERY_STRING.

Comment: Like @nategoose said, the "damage" was done by the browser before your server ever received it. (Check the access logs and you'll see.)

Answer (score 6):

```
  char *data = malloc(200);
  data=getenv("QUERY_STRING");
```

Memory leak here. You're allocating 200 bytes you'll never use or be able to `free()`. (Or not, for `malloc()` may fail and return `NULL`.)

```
  char m[200];
  sscanf(data,"%s", m);
```

This is a crude replacement for `strcpy()`/`strncpy()`. Results in a buffer overflow if the query string is more than 200 characters long. Also terminates as soon as it finds a whitespace, but that's not a problem becuase they've been turned to `+` or `%20` during URL encoding.

```
  ptr=fopen("c:/test.txt", "w");
  fprintf(ptr, "%s", m);
```

`fopen()` may fail, resulting in a return value of `NULL`.

I suggest you review pointers and memory allocation, look up some string manipulation functions other than printf/scanf and also make a habit of checking for errors, i.e. coding defensively. Even in small, example-quality code.

Answer (score 1):

The `%3A` type stuff is the HTTP hexadecimal encoding of characters which may be special.  It is just like escaping the quote character in a C string.  `"\""`

The PATH environmental variable has nothing to do with HTTP, so it is not effected.  Your web server program is setting the QUERY_STRING to what the web browser sent, which has the % hex encoding in it.